# A copy of [middleware] has been removed from the module tree but is still active! - error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, middleware

We use rails version **2.3.5**

This error has been reported in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991113/how-do-i-use-domain-objects-from-middleware-with-cache-classes-off)

I tried the following:

- adding **config.cache_class = true** - the problem with this was that, the server had to be restarted every time a change was made to any controller. Also the server start time was too long
- adding **unloadable** to the middleware - no use
- adding **config.middleware.use [middleware]** to development.rb - no use

Is there a way to overcome this other than making development similar to production?

**Edit**

even tried adding **config.middleware.use [middleware]** to environment.rb. Well this behaved totally different. My error disappeared, but my middleware cracked. All it's objects were nil..!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
 adding config.middleware.use [middleware] to environment.rb
```

this was not working previously for me because i was initializing this middle ware inside **session_store** too. So the same middle ware was executed twice with the second time all params with **nil** - Hence the nil problem.

Thank you rogerdpack for trying to help.!

Answer (score 0):

maybe you need to make a plugin reloadable?
refs: http://blog.yves-vogl.me/2010/01/12/automatically-reload-rails-plugins/
[Rails auto-reloading plug in development mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1633852/rails-auto-reloading-plug-in-development-mode)
et al

Comment: sorry.. but is a plugin and a middleware same.?

Comment: I'm not sure but there may be something similar.